# Portugol esperando um valor do tipo "real"

Tags: portugol

Estou com um problema em meu pseudocódigo, quando executo ele informa que:

> a entrada de dados do programa esperava um valor do tipo 'real', mas nenhum valor foi informado ou o valor informado é de outro tipo;

Como resolver isso?

```
programa
{
    funcao inicio()
    {
        real N1, N2, N3, MEDIA
        inteiro QTD, cont
        escreva("\nDigite a qualtidade de alunos que deseja calcular a media: ")
        leia (QTD)
        cont = 0
        (cont< QTD) faca
        {
            leia(N1)
            leia(N2)
            leia(N3)    
        } enquanto(cont< QTD)
        se (N2>=N3)
            MEDIA=(N1+N2)/2
        senao
            MEDIA=(N1+N3)/2
        se(MEDIA>=6)
            escreva("\nAluno aprovado, Media:\n", MEDIA)
        senao
            escreva("\nAluno reprovado, Media:\n ", MEDIA)
            {

            }       
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: antes de mais nada gostaria de lembrá-lo que o portugol espera uma sintaxe bem definida, e não um pseudo-código

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem um erro de lógica falta incrementar `cont` se não ele sempre vai ser menor quer `QTD`

nesse codigo adicione a linha `cont = cont + 1` após leia(N3)

```
  faca{
        leia(N1)
        leia(N2)
        leia(N3)    
 } enquanto(cont< QTD)
```

ou seja seu código vai ficar assim:

```
    faca{
         leia(N1)
        leia(N2)
        leia(N3)    
        cont = cont + 1 //linha nova 
 } enquanto(cont< QTD)
```

Comment: @Deyel Eu testei aqui, funcinou com o `(cont< QTD)` antes do `faça`. quando vc tenta imprimir: `(cont< QTD)` ele retorna `verdadeiro`.

Comment: OK, me ajudou bastante, obrigado mesmo, seu nome no perfil me assustou no começo, pensei perdi oque? mais por que eu tava começando a usar o stackoverflow a poco tempo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 7):

O seu laço de repetição `faça-enquanto` está errado, ele está assim:

```
(cont< QTD) faca
{
 leia(N1)
leia(N2)
leia(N3)    
} enquanto(cont< QTD)
```

Enquanto ele deveria ser assim:

```
faca
{
   leia(N1)
   leia(N2)
   leia(N3)    
   cont++  //incremento do contador
} enquanto(cont< QTD)
```

Você deve escrever a condição de parada apenas após o `enquanto` no seu código você havia escrito a condição de parada duas vezes.

Outro erro que você encontraria após consertar seu laço de repetição é o contador que não incrementa, logo, vc ficaria em um loop infinito

PS: Lembre-se de identar seu código

Comment: o erro ainda continua, quando isso não acontece quando pede pra min digitar a nota de cada aluno fica se repetindo infinitamente sem um resultado exato.

Comment: @matheusferreira sim, você não está incrementando seu cont, note que eu escrevi isso na resposta

Comment: Math com Math se entendem.

Comment: Resolvendo problemas de Math?